# Align a checkbox input and a <p> tag in the same line

Tags: html, css, alignment, frontend, forms

I've seen most of the other solutions to this problem using a label. Unfortunately, I can't use label on this particular case, because that will mess things up. What I have is the following:

```
<div className="terms-checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" required />
  <p>I accept the Terms and Conditions</p>
</div>
```

And I'm setting display to be inline-block for `terms-checkbox` like so:

```
    .terms-checkbox {
      display: inline-block;
    }
```

However, this does not align the items horizontally/in the same line. Without wrapping the `input` tag with `label`, how can I make the checkbox and `p` tag align horizontally?

Here's the fiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/eu5rso2a/1/

edit: fixed indentation.

Comment: instead of `p` use `span`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must set the `terms-checkbox` class to input or p tag. Not their parent.
Means your `input` and `p` tag must be `inline-block`

Answer (score 1):

```
<p><input type="checkbox" required/>I accept the Terms and Conditions</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set style `vertical-align: "sub";` on the input (you can also try setting it to "bottom" if that's applicable)