# Place checkbox inline with paragraph text

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox, twitter-bootstrap-3

How can i put that checkbox inline with the text?

The html code is:

```
<div class="checkbox checkbox_allow_div"><label class="label_300"><input type="checkbox" name="allow" value="1" class="allow_checkbox"><?php echo gdpr_text('gdpr_order_text'); ?></label></div>
```

The text, that i echo with php, its comeing from sql table, and its writed in a ckeditor on the admin page. Ckeditor put the text automatically in `<p>` tags.

I cant put the checkbox code into that texts html code, bacause the user is writing the text on the admin page, so its always dynamic.

[image]

Comment: please show us working code (not php ....)

Comment: I cant because i dont know how to use everything on the site. There is the checkbox, and the text is in <p></p> tag, not more.

Comment: You should try to put 2 divs,1 for check box and 1 for text and float them with apprropriate width

Comment: You'd have to include all relevant code in order for someone to be able to help you.

If the text you want to put inline with the checkbox is indeed being insert as a `p` element, then the solution to your problem is a simple one as shown here https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qLVobV

Answer (score 1):

Add `display:inline-block` for input and paragraph.

```css
.checkbox input,
.checkbox p {
  display: inline-block
}
```

```html
<div class="checkbox checkbox_allow_div">
  <label class="label_300">
    <input type="checkbox" name="allow" value="1" class="allow_checkbox">
    <p>Random Text</p>
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: But its doing nothing. I added it also in inline, but nothing. I also tryed this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51922044/align-a-checkbox-input-and-a-p-tag-in-the-same-line

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure that the checkbox is not defined as a block with:

```
.checkbox_allow_div {
  display: inline-block'
}
```

then, you can style the label that is around the checkbox and the text's p tag with:

```
label {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
}
```

More information on Flexbox: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/